# Failing to read frames from stream after interrupt

Tags: c, multithreading, ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg to read and decode a network video stream.  I have the read/decode stuff happening on a dedicated thread.  Occasionally, I would like to join on that thread.  To do this, I've tried specifying an interrupt callback and flags to indicate that reads should be non-blocking.  I have most of the basics working, but I'm running into an issue with my **av_read_frame** after an interrupt.  Here's the basic structure:

```
void read()
{
    AVPacket pkt;

    while (shouldRead)
    {
        if (av_read_frame(formatCtx, &pkt)
        {
            // succesfully read frame
        }
        else
        {
            // failed to read frame
        }
    }
}

int interrupt_cb(void* param)
{
    return shouldInterrupt;
}

void initialize() 
{
    formatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
    formatCtx->flags |= AVFMT_FLAG_NONBLOCK;
    formatCtx->flags |= AVIO_FLAG_NONBLOCK;
    formatCtx->interrupt_callback.callback = interrupt_cb;

    // ...other initialization stuff (e.g. avformat_open_input, etc.)
}
```

After initialization, everything looks fine - I happily chug along reading frames.  However, if I ever try to interrupt by setting **shouldInterrupt** to **true**, all subsequent **av_read_frame** calls fail.  Also, the interrupt callback never gets called again.  Digging into the code a bit, I see that formatCtx->packet_buffer is empty.  Given that, it makes sense that the reads fail.  How do I resume reading after the interrupt then?  I'd rather not have to tear down completely to resume reading and decoding.

UPDATE:  I recently discovered that there's an AVIO_FLAG_NONBLOCK flag as well.  I tried that but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: 'Occasionally, I would like to join on that thread' - FFS why?

Comment: @Martin - Like I said, I create a thread for reading and decoding the stream (off of the UI thread). I need that thread to stop when the app stops or pauses. Doing that in a graceful way is preferable.